# Prove that this set is closed

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

Let $C$ be the set of continuous real valued functions on $[0,1]$ with metric

$$d(f,g) = \text{sup} \{ |f(x) - g(x)| \ : x \in \ [0,1]\}$$

Show that $X = \{ f \ \in \ C \ : \ f(0) =0 \}$ is a closed subset of $C$.

I don't know how to prove this one.

Please help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hint: take a sequence in $X$ which converges to some $f$. Observe that by your definitions, this convergence is uniform, which implies pointwise convergence. Then $f(0) = 0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For $(f_{n})\subseteq X$ such that $d(f_{n},f)\rightarrow 0$, then $|f(0)|\leq|f_{n}(0)-f(0)|+|f_{n}(0)|=|f_{n}(0)-f(0)|\leq d(f_{n},f)\rightarrow 0$, so $f(0)=0$.

Comment: I can't understand your argument. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: I used sequential characterisation of closed sets, do you know such a characterisation?

Comment: Given a set $S$ in $C$ is closed if and only if given any sequence $(f_{n})\subseteq S$ is such that $f_{n}\rightarrow f$ in $C$, then $f\in S$.

Comment: Ohk. Thanks a lot! +1